# Modeling recursive breakdown structures in graph database

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, neo4j-node

For recursive breakdown structures, is it better to model as ...
    a.  Group HAS Subgroup... or
    b.  Subgroup PART_OF Group ?? .... 
Some neo4j tutorials imply model both (the parent_of and child_of example) while the neo4j subtype tutorials imply that either will work fine (generally going with PART-OF).

Based on experience with neo4j, is there a practical reason for choosing one or the other or use both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

Representing the same logical relationship with a pair of relationships (having different types) in opposite directions is a very bad idea and a waste of time and resources. Neo4j can traverse a single relationship just as easily from either of its nodes.

With respect to which direction to pick (since we do not want both), see [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531596/graph-database-newbie-q-how-to-decide-on-the-direction-of-a-relation-between-2/40538970#40538970).

Comment: Just to note, there are exceptions of course, driven by the needs of your data. A big one is relationships which are not necessarily reciprocal. For example if a :Person has a :Follows relationship to another :Person, that doesn't logically imply that the other :Person follows back...it will require a second relationship in the other direction. Similar situations may occur for relationships of different types.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I understand your point. But my answer still holds, since it recommends against always using a pair of relationships (having different types) in opposite directions. I have updated my answer to hopefully make that more clear.

Comment: I should have clarified my comment wasn't any kind of criticism of your answer, yours is absolutely correct, this was more of a note for Dave and others to keep in mind.

Comment: And, after reading the direction question, I would infer that the PARENT_OF relation would be preferred as (all) children have a parent (PERSON) but not all PERSONs have a child.  Same for GROUP and subgroups. ... Point up not down.

Comment: @Dave Actually, that consideration should not matter. If there are no technical reasons to pick one direction, I would pick whichever one feels more natural to you for the data  model, or even whichever one results in a shorter name for the relationship type.

Comment: Thank you both, cybersam and @InverseFalcon.  Very helpful.  As an old RDBM information engineer, the child using a foreign key to point to the parent feels more natural.  Thanks for the quick responses.